# Interpreting coded field in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

Having this table, I would like to find the rows with Val fitting my Indata.

Tol field is a tolerance (varchar), that can be either an integer/float or a percentage value.

```
Row Val Tol   Outdata
1   24  0     A
2   24  5     B
3   24  10    C
4   32  %10   D
5   32  1     E
```

Indata 30 for example should match rows 3 (24+10=34) and 4 (32-10%=28.8).

Can this be done in mySQL? CREATE FUNCTION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a MySQL install to test it on, but this example is converted from Oracle sql syntax.  You have to use string functions to determine if the `tol` is a percent and act accordingly to calculate the min and max range for that field.  Then you can use a between clause.

```
select * 
  from (select t.*,
               case when substr(tol, 1, 1) = '%' then 
                      t.val * (1 + convert('.' + substr(tol, 2), number))
                    else 
                      t.val + convert(tol, number)
               end maxval,
               case when substr(tol, 1, 1) = '%' then 
                      t.val * (1 - convert('.' + substr(tol, 2), number))
                    else convert(t.val - tol, number)
               end minval
          from mytable
       ) t
where 30 between minval and maxval
;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have not yet tried it, but this was what I was looking for! But 30 seems strange....

Comment: What happens if someone enters "10%" instead of the "%10" you were expecting? This is a fragile solution.

Comment: @Petter Magnusson: That 30 is what you gave for your example "Indata 30 for example should match rows 3 and 4".  Substitute whatever value you want to compare.

Comment: @Alison R.:  I was assuming that leading % sign was a fixed specification.  You could use a position function and replace if the % sign could be at any location in the string.

Comment: Ah, right! Will test it and get back. Also the % can be assumed to be in a fixed first position.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be rather difficult to do in MySQL with that table and column design. How do you plan to differentiate what sort of comparison should be done? By doing a string comparison to see if your varchar field contains a percentage sign?

I would suggest breaking your tolerance field into (at least) two int/float columns, say `tol` and `tol_pct`. For flexibility, I would represent `tol_pct` as a decimal (10% => .10). Then, you can do a query that looks like:

```
select * 
from table 
where
    (Indata between Val - tol and Val + tol) 
    or (Indata between Val * (1 + tol_pct) and Val * (1 - tol_pct))
```

Comment: Not sure how MySQL handles NULLS, but you may need to add some checking here.

Indata between Val - coalesce(tol, 0)...

Comment: I don't have a MySQL instance at my disposal at the moment, so I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP. Each "branch" of the where clause could also be prefaced with something like `tol is not null AND...`

Comment: I was aware of this solution, and it may well be the way I go, but for this question I wanted to know if if could be done the other way. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done. But let me tell you that you better review your database design as it conflicts with normalization quite a bit. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization for a quick overview.